# Adding a class to checked input

Tags: jquery

I want to do sth like this: if one of inputs is defautly selected add the class to his table parent.
I have original code which adds or removes the class to chosen input:

```
$('.table tr.table-selection').click(function() {
$('.table tr').removeClass('success').find('input').prop('checked', false); 
$(this).addClass('success').find('input').prop('checked', true); 
});
```

So, I tried to add similar code:

```
$('.table tr.table-selection').ready(function() {
$(this).addClass('success').find('input').prop('checked', true); 
});
```

But it doesn't work. I'm not well familiar with jQuery, what should I change?

Comment: Can you please `html` for better understanding

Comment: .ready(function() needs to be replaced with .click(function()

Comment: @Gerard, but I don't want to make it on click, I want to make that happen on load

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then update your question.

Comment: If you want to make it happen on load, then why not just put it in the HTML directly?  Why use `jquery` at all?

Comment: I'm curious how do you even check the element on page load...Can't you add the class also where you check the input?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following to run it on load:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.table tr.table-selection')
  .addClass('success').find('input').prop('checked', true); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use :

```
    $('.table tr.table-selection').on("click", function(){
          $(this).addClass('success').find('input').prop('checked', 
          true);
    })
```

[EDIT] If you want on load maybe just do this :

```
    $('.table tr.tableselection').addClass('success').find('input').prop('checked',true);})
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check rather input defaultly comes checked or not, you don't need to write an `.click(function(){})`

you only need to write an if/else condition like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var checkControl = $('.table tr.table-selection');
    if(checkControl.find('input').prop('checked', true)){
       $(this).addClass('success');
    }else{
        $(this).addClass('fail');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it almost works, but it adds the class to all inputs, not only to this one with checked="checked" value. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: sorry for late response, i made a terrible mistake, my code adds 'succes' to every input if any of input checked. You need fix the  `checkControl.addClass('success');` part with this: `$(this).addClass('success');` so it will add 'succes' class to only checked one. I will edit the code on the top also